# Is it possible to turn off an EC2 instance without losing installed programs and data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I launched an EC2 Windows Server via AWS and connected to it via remote desktop. I installed Anaconda and a trading platform (TWS). I would like to only pay for the instance while I'm using it, and there are many days when I don't need it, but I am being billed hourly. Is there a way to pause it/use it on an as-needed basis without wiping the installed programs and data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of disk volumes on EC2. The default, most common type is [EBS](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/), which will save the contents of the disk volume while the instance is in the `stopped` state.

The other disk volume type is [instance store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html) volumes, which are ephemeral, meaning they are cleared each time you stop the instance. Only certain EC2 instance types will have instance storage.

---

You can also add AWS [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) volumes to EC2 instances, which is network file storage that can be shared by multiple EC2 instances, and exist independently of your EC2 instances.

Comment: Simple answer: Yes, you can turn it off. You don't lose anything unless you specifically configured it that way.